Defining matrix multiplication via contractions and tensor products
I recently read somewhere that matrix multiplication can be viewed as a "composition of first forming the tensor product and a contraction". I liked that view, because it shows why one cannot expect to generalize matrix multiplication to higher tensors and also gave me a somewhat better understanding of the trace. I understand this thus:
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Clearly the composition map $ \mathcal{comp}: End(V)\times End(V)\to End(V)$ is bilinear, so by the universal property we get a linear map $End(V)\otimes End(V)\to End(V).$ By $End(V)\cong V\otimes V^*$ and the associativity of the tensor product we can get a linear map $\mathcal{tr}: V\otimes V^*\otimes V\otimes V^*\to End(V)$ such that everything commutes:
$$End(V) \times End(V)  \longrightarrow V\otimes V^*\otimes V\otimes V^*$$
$$\overset{\mathcal{comp}}{\searrow}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\overset{tr}{\swarrow} $$
$$End(V)$$
Now expressing this in a basis shows that this map, suggestively named, is the contraction over the "inner two" components of our product. I was wondering if there is a way to see this without having to resort to a basis? Put naively, why not contract over any other components, or what role does contraction (about which I only learned a short while ago, and about which I not have much intuition) play here more abstractly? Are there any defining (maybe "universal") properties of contractions that come into play here?
Many thanks!

You can just work out what all the other possible contractions are. You get matrix multiplication in the other order, then the maps $(M, N) \mapsto M \text{tr}(N)$ and $N \text{tr}(M)$.

@Qiaochu Yuan Yes I was aware of that, I just wanted to know whether there is a natural way to exclude this option instead of just checking. I imagined there would be an argument something like "it has this property, so its a contraction. By another property, it has to be THIS contraction". But alas its fairly straigtforward:)

Let $v \in V$, $\varphi \in V^\ast$. Then $v \otimes \varphi \in V \otimes V^\ast$ represents the endomorphism,
$$L_{v \otimes \varphi}(w) = \varphi(w)v, \forall w \in V$$
Thus,
$$(L_{v \otimes \varphi} \circ L_{w \otimes \psi})(x) = L_{v \otimes \varphi}(\psi(x)w) = \psi(x)\varphi(w)v = \varphi(w)L_{v \otimes \psi}(x)$$
That is, $L_{v \otimes \varphi} \circ L_{w \otimes \psi} = \varphi(w)L_{v \otimes \psi}$, which is exactly the result of contracting the middle two components, $\varphi$ and $w$. Now the result follows by extending by linearity.

In a sense, a more conceptual understanding of what is happening here is that rank-one maps span $\text{End}(V)$, and rank-one maps are exactly those that factors through the underlying field $\mathbb{K}$, i.e., $f \in \text{End}(V)$ is of rank-one (or the zero map) iff it can be written as,
$\require{AMScd}$
$$f = \begin{CD}
V @<h<< \mathbb{K} @<g<< V
\end{CD}$$
$g$ is an element of $V^\ast$, while $h$ can be identified with $h(1) \in V$ and thus regarded as an element of $V$. This is how $f$ is identified with an element of $V \otimes V^\ast$ - namely, it is identified with $h \otimes g$. So the composition of rank-one maps can be represented as,
$$f_1 \circ f_2 =  \begin{CD}
V @<h_1<< \mathbb{K} @<g_1<< V @<h_2<< \mathbb{K} @<g_2<< V
\end{CD}$$
If we consider what is the composition of the middle two maps, $g_1$ and $h_2$, it is exactly multiplying by the scalar $g_1(h_2)$, which is exactly the contraction of the middle two tensor components. The leftmost and rightmost tensor components do not need to be changed, since we want our end result to be a diagram $V \leftarrow \mathbb{K} \leftarrow V$.

great, this is just what i meant, thanks! ...more straightforward then i thought...

your add-on is a really good explanation, thanks again! ... I never realised this symmetry, eg. $Hom(K,V)\cong V$ and $Hom(V,K)\cong V^*$, that makes it clear:)
